# How to read a variable from another class

Tags: php, oop

I have the situation below and i don't know how to make that:

```
class A {
public fuction a1()
{
     $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
}

class B extends A {
public function b1()
{
    // how to echo the variable "$time" in class B?
}
}
```

Comment: Call parent method like this `parent::a1();` ?

Comment: `$time` does not exist outside of the method. You should make it  a class property or return it from the method so that you can use the value.

Comment: Just thought, can you call direct function a1() inside b1() will it work

Answer (score 2):

You can **PHP**'s [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) keyword, and [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) the value from function `a1()`.

So your code will look something like this,

```
<?php
class A
{
    public static function a1()
    {
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        return $time;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function b1()
    {
        echo parent::a1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<?php
class A
{
    public static function a1()
    {
       echo  $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function b1()
    {
       $this->a1();
    }
}

$object = new B;
$object->b1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 approach:

**`First:`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Class A
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * Class Property (Class Var)
     * @var public
     */
    public $time;

    /**
     * a1
     * Set date time in class property $time
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function a1()
    {
        $this->time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}

/**
 * Class B extends Class A
 */
class B extends A
{
    /**
     * b1
     * Call Parent Class A method first to set date time
     * then echo time output
     * @return string Parent Class T$time value
     */
    public function b1()
    {
        // first init the time value from parent class method
        $this->a1();

        // now show or get the parent class property
        return $this->time;
    }
}

/**
 * Class Object B
 * @var B
 */
$B = new B();

// call B Class method b1 to echo time
echo $B->b1();
```

**`Second:`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Class A
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * Class Property (Class Var)
     * @var public
     */
    public $time;

    /**
     * a1
     * Set date time in class property $time
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function a1()
    {
        // set date time
        $this->time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        // return set class property value
        return $this->time;
    }
}

/**
 * Class B extends Class A
 */
class B extends A
{
    /**
     * b1
     * Call Parent Class A method first to set date time
     * then echo time output
     * @return string Parent Class T$time value
     */
    public function b1()
    {
        // first init the time value from parent class method
        return $this->a1();
    }
}

/**
 * Class Object B
 * @var B
 */
$B = new B();

// call B Class method b1 to echo time
echo $B->b1();
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can declare your variable in the first class without a function.

```
class A()
{
     protected static $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

}

class B extends A 
{
    public function b1()
    {
        echo parent::$time;
    }
}
```

You can use the time variable anywhere you want in the code without instantiating the A class. Also "$time" variable doesn't have to be static.